# Hazelcast Profiling on Operations

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have an application which has Hazelcast running in embedded mode. I have enabled diagnostics using https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1/management/diagnostics.html which is logging metrics to separate file.

```
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.metric.level=debug
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.invocation.sample.period.seconds=300
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.pending.invocations.period.seconds=300
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.slowoperations.period.seconds=300
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.storeLatency.period.seconds=300
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.metrics.period.seconds=300
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.memberinfo.period.second=300
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.directory=/u/tomcat/appn/logs
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.max.rolled.file.size.mb=200
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.max.rolled.file.count=5
```

The problem here is in the metrics generated for Operations profile there is no mention of iMap which are being used.
The log snippet is as shown below:

```
 11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalPutLatency]=102]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalSetLatency]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalGetLatency]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalMaxPutLatency]=94]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalMaxSetLatency]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalMaxGetLatency]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalMaxRemoveLatency]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.totalRemoveLatency]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.lastAccessTime]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.lastUpdateTime]=1623429796822]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.hits]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.numberOfOtherOperations]=1]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.numberOfEvents]=30]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.getCount]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.putCount]=30]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.setCount]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.removeCount]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=ms,metric=map.creationTime]=1623429781163]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.ownedEntryCount]=30]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=count,metric=map.backupEntryCount]=0]
11-06-2021 12:47:56 1623430076148 Metric[[name=employeeCache,unit=bytes,metric=map.ownedEntryMemoryCost]=52775]
```

**However when i look at operations profile below it does show the operations being done like Get, Put but does not show on which cache i.e. name of that cache**

Logs showing operations profile:

```
11-06-2021 13:54:11 1623434051149 OperationsProfiler[
                          com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.ContainsKeyOperation[
                                  count=21
                                  totalTime(us)=1,637
                                  avg(us)=77
                                  max(us)=589
                                  latency-distribution[
                                          16..31us=9
                                          32..63us=11
                                          256..511us=1]]
                          com.hazelcast.client.impl.operations.GetConnectedClientsOperation[
                                  count=1
                                  totalTime(us)=6,896
                                  avg(us)=6,896
                                  max(us)=6,896
                                  latency-distribution[
                                          4096..8191us=1]]
                          com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.operations.RegistrationOperation[
                                  count=125
                                  totalTime(us)=2,879
                                  avg(us)=23
                                  max(us)=108
                                  latency-distribution[
                                          8..15us=100
                                          16..31us=21
                                          32..63us=3
                                          64..127us=1]]
                          com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapGetInvalidationMetaDataOperation[
                                  count=191
                                  totalTime(us)=140,066
                                  avg(us)=733
                                  max(us)=40,709
                                  latency-distribution[
                                          32..63us=7
                                          64..127us=31
                                          128..255us=79
                                          256..511us=61
                                          512..1023us=9
                                          1024..2047us=1
                                          2048..4095us=1
                                          8192..16383us=1
                                          16384..32767us=1]]
                          com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryOperation[
                                  count=178
                                  totalTime(us)=276,769
                                  avg(us)=1,554
                                  max(us)=21,650
                                  latency-distribution[
                                          64..127us=32
                                          128..255us=10
                                          256..511us=24
                                          512..1023us=65
                                          1024..2047us=38
                                          2048..4095us=3
                                          4096..8191us=2
                                          8192..16383us=4]]
                          com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutOperation[
                                  count=8,905
                                  totalTime(us)=555,519
                                  avg(us)=62
                                  max(us)=95,164
                                  latency-distribution[
                                          8..15us=377
                                          16..31us=6,869
                                          32..63us=1,176
                                          64..127us=408
                                          128..255us=51
                                          256..511us=15
                                          512..1023us=3
                                          1024..2047us=1
                                          8192..16383us=4
                                          32768..65535us=1]]]
```

***The requirement here is to show both cache name inside operations profiler in diagnostics logs of hazelcast.***

Answer (score 1):

Name of the cache in Diagnostics is not really relevant because Diagnostics logs are about providing information about operations. These operations are the events (get, put, query etc) that arrive at the members and the diagnosis is about how these events are being processed i.e. how these events are being consumed by the internal processing threads. Map/Cache names are also irrelevant because all maps/caches are distributed i.e. the data is spread across all members in the cluster. If a particular operation is slow then it means that its slow for the data stored in that partition on that member from all the maps/caches.

However, if this is something absolutely necessary to your case and if you are enthusiastic about building this then feel free to create a PR and submit at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast